# Почему не выводится коректно информация в файл

Tags: python, файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я прокручиваю значения двух переменных от 0 до 2 включительно , и записываю промежуточный результат в файл, но значение последней переменной не записывается

```
flog=open('example.txt','w')
flog.close()
for t0 in range(0,3,1):
   for t1 in range(0,3,1):
       flog=open('example.txt','a')
       print('.',str(t0)+str(t1))
       flog.write('\n\n======================')
       flog.write("\n\n t0 = "+str(t0)+" ,t1 = "+str(t1))
```

Последнее значение должно быть t0=2 t1=2 но t1 останавливается на 1

Comment: Запустил Ваш код у себя, он прекрасно справился с обозначенным Вами функционалом

Comment: я загрузил скриншот файла в котором  у меня после компиляции показано что t1=1последнее

Comment: Возможно, информация застряла в буфере. Попробуйте закрыть файл после работы с ним.

Comment: Спасибо , это помогло